# Как загрузить фотографию на сервер с помощью flask.forms и MongoDB

Tags: python, http, mongodb, flask, backend

Я хочу чтобы при регистрации на моем сайте пользователь вводил свой никнейм, почту и пароль, поле user_point нужно для подсчет баллов, оно не столь важно, и по возможности добавлял фото ( при ее отсутствии я ее буду заменять на дефолтную), у меня выдается ошибка вида:
**TypeError: must specify an encoding for file in order to write str**
Не мог ли бы вы подсказать, как это починить, проверка на то что картинка имеет надлежащее расширение желательна, но не обязательна.

Мой **views.py**:

```
@air.route('/create_account/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create_account():
    form = AddUser()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.user_photo.data == "":
            user = User(
                user_password=form.user_password.data,
                user_nick=form.user_nick.data,
                user_photo="default.jpg",
                user_email=form.user_email.data,
                user_point=0,
            )
        else:
            user = User(
                user_password=form.user_password.data,
                user_nick=form.user_nick.data,
                user_photo=form.user_photo.data,
                user_email=form.user_email.data,
                user_point=0

            )
        if User.objects(user_nick=form.user_nick.data).first() == None:
            user.save()
            login_user(user)
        else:
            flash("Аккаунт с таким именем существует, придумайте другое")
            return redirect("/create_account")
        return redirect(url_for("shop.login"))

    return render_template("create_account.html", form=form, user=current_user)
```

Мой **models.py**:

```
class AddUser(Form):
    user_nick = StringField("Ваш никнейм", validators=[InputRequired(message="Поле не должно быть пустым1")])
    user_password = PasswordField("Ваш пароль", validators=[InputRequired(message="Поле не должно быть пустым2")])
    user_email = StringField("Ваш email", validators=[InputRequired(message="Поле не должно быть пустым3")])
    user_photo = FileField("Фото профиля")
    submit = SubmitField('Добавить')
```

И мой **forms.py**:

```
class User(db.Document, UserMixin):
    user_id = db.SequenceField()
    user_nick = db.StringField()
    user_email = db.StringField()
    user_photo = db.FileField()
    user_point = db.IntField()
    user_password = db.StringField()
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел ответ на свой вопрос:
https://docs-python.ru/packages/veb-frejmvork-flask-python/zagruzka-fajlov-server-flask/
Вот код views.py:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, IMAGES, patch_request_class
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileRequired, FileAllowed
from wtforms import SubmitField

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'I have a dream'
# нужно будет создать папку с именем 'uploads'
app.config['UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST'] = os.path.join(basedir, 'uploads') 

photos = UploadSet('photos', IMAGES)
configure_uploads(app, photos)
# максимальный размер файла, по умолчанию 16MB
patch_request_class(app)  


class UploadForm(FlaskForm):
    photo = FileField(validators=[FileAllowed(photos, 'Image only!'), 
                      FileRequired('File was empty!')])
    submit = SubmitField('Upload')


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    form = UploadForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        filename = photos.save(form.photo.data)
        file_url = photos.url(filename)
    else:
        file_url = None
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, file_url=file_url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Код index.html:

```
{# index.html #}
{# Создайте папку с именем templates, поместите в нее этот файл #}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Upload File</title>
<h1>Photo Upload</h1>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
     {{ form.photo }}
     {% for error in form.photo.errors %}
         <span style="color: red;">{{ error }}</span>
     {% endfor %}
     {{ form.submit }}
</form>

{% if file_url %}
<br>
<img src="{{ file_url }}">
{% endif %}
```

В случае ошибки вида: flask_uploads: ImportError: cannot import name 'secure_filename'
Стоит заменить в файле:
flask_updates.py
строку:

```
from werkzeug import secure_filename,FileStorage
```

На строки:

```
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from werkzeug.datastructures import  FileStorage
```